# Javascript Nested Object Representation in Rails Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This could be a very basic question but forgive my limitless of my knowledge. How would you represent Js nested object (Backbone Model) in Rails Model ?

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: ShortId,
  name :{
    first: {type: String},
    last: {type: String}
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mongoid model would be

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :first, type: String
  field :last, type: String
end
```

There's the issue of mapping from Mongoid/MongoDB "_id" to Backbone "id".  The choices to address this are summarized in several discussions that can be Googled, an example is http://dzello.com/blog/2011/12/24/tame-the-mongoid-id-field-in-your-rails-and-backbone-js-app/

Different people have chosen either of the two solutions, telling Backbone to use "_id" or rewriting #to_json in Mongoid to "id".  Either will work, you may want to experiment to see what you prefer.